# Ajax response not executing in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I get this in my server log, which seems to indicate that it returned ajaxresponse.js.erb:

```
Started GET "/ajaxresponse" for 70.28.21.25 at 2013-10-01 15:38:54 +0000
Processing by ContentController#ajaxresponse as JS
  Rendered content/ajaxresponse.js.erb within layouts/content (0.5ms)
  Rendered inc/_analytics.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 46ms (Views: 45.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Inside ajaxresponse.js.erb :

```
$('#ajaxdiv').append("fdsa");
```

There is a div on the page with ID "ajaxdiv"

but it doesn't seem to change anything?  I've tried 100 different javascript commands within the .js.erb file, but none of them are affecting the page.

Controller action:

```
def ajaxresponse
 respond_to do |format|
    format.js   {}
  end
end
```

Chrome console log :

```
Uncaught Error: jquery-ujs has already been loaded!
```

Edit:  Just remoted jquery-ujs from the application.rb file and there are no more errors.  The page, however, still doesn't update with ajax

The ajaxdiv is below the save button and has default text: "ohai"

Answer (score 0):

To get a div with the id "ajaxdiv", you need to use `#ajaxdiv`, not `ajaxdiv`:

```
$('#ajaxdiv').append("fdsa");
```